# Call a class by string PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm calling a class by a string variable passed on a function argument.

> ApiTester.php

```
   use MyApp\Sites\Site;

   abstract class ApiTester extends TestCase() {

   /**
     * Make a new record in the DB
     * 
     * @param $type
     * @param array $fields
     * @throws BadMethodCallException
     */
    protected function make($type, array $fields = [])
    {
        while($this->times--)
        {
            $stub = array_merge($this->getStub(), $fields);

            $type::create($stub);
        }


    }
```

> SitesTester.php

```
class SitesTester extends ApiTester() {

/** @test */
public function it_fetches_a_single_site()
{
    // arrange
    $this->make('Site');

    // act
    $site = $this->getJson('api/v1/sites/1')->data;

    // assertion
    $this->assertResponseOk();

    $this->assertObjectHasAttributes($site, 'name', 'address');
}
```

> Site.php // Eloquent Model

```
namespace MyApp\Sites;

class Site extends \Eloquent {

}
```

But if I call the class that the string variable `$type` contains, for example; string variable `$type` contains 'Site', it says class 'Site' not found.

I tried to manually type `Site::create($stub)` and finally accepts it.

I also tried
`call_user_func($type::create(), $stub);`
and
`$model = new $type;
$model->create($stub);`
 
but unfortunately it says class 'Site' not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because you only have class `SiteTester` or are you not showing some code of yours?

Comment: what do you mean? @Justinas?

Comment: `class SitesTester extends ApiTester()`

Comment: What Justinas has pointed out is you are using the literal name of 'Site'. We do not see anything to do with that name in your code. We can see SitesTester.. but not Site.

Comment: @Justinas, what should it be?

Comment: @NeilMasters, oh, my bad. 'Site' is a eloquent class. I declared it on my ApiTester abstract class.
`use Sites\Site;`

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:

```
class X {
    static function foo($arg) {
        return 'hi ' . $arg;
    }
};

$cls = 'X';

print call_user_func("$cls::foo", 'there');
```

If your php is very old (<5.3 I believe), you have to use an array instead:

```
print call_user_func(array($cls, "foo"), 'there');
```

Comment: OP is looking for params too, so you migh be changing that answer to `call_user_func_array`. The PHP version thing is not relevant now because it's only related to class keywords like `parent` and `self` etc.

Comment: @georg: I tried `call_user_func("$type::create", $stub);` but it says `call_user_func()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Answer (score 0):

You may want to replace that `static class call` with the following :

```
        while( $this->times-- )
        {
            $stub = array_merge( $this->getStub(), $fields );

            call_user_func( "$type::create",  $stub );
        }
```

Runnable code here : http://runnable.com/VIqy4CDePeY-AeMV/output

Comment: I think laravel is looking eloquent models in app\models folder even though I already require the eloquent classes at the ApiTester class. So, I move my Site.php file into app\models directory from MyApp\Sites directory. And I just use the `$type::create($stub);` and it worked. So I think the problem is if you call a eloquent class via string variable, it looks at the app\models directory.